# @Post method with capturing parenthesis in @Path not matched in Jersey

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs, grizzly

I am having trouble getting JAX-RS POST methods to match with Jersey. Verbatim paths work fine ("/prefix/ABC/DEF"), but parenthesised captures ("/prefix/{alpha}/{beta}") fail to trigger. Here are the methods in question, as defined in the server interface, using Jersey.

```
public interface CollectorEndpoint
{
    ...
    @POST
    @Path("/prefix/{alpha}/{beta}") //doesn't match
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    Response method1(@PathParam("alpha") String alpha,
                     @PathParam("beta") String beta,
                     String jsonContent);
    @POST
    @Path("/prefix/ABC/DEF")        //works for that one specific case
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    Response method2(String jsonContent);
    ...
}
```

And here in the implementation class:

```
@Path("/collect")
public class RestCollectorEndpoint implements CollectorEndpoint {
    ...
    @Override
    public Response method1(@PathParam("alpha") String alpha,
                            @PathParam("beta") String beta,
                            String jsonContent) {...}

    @Override
    public Response method2(String jsonContent);
    ...
}
```

I get the following logs:

```
Matching path [/prefix/notabc/notdef]
X-Jersey-Tracing-010: MATCH       [ ---- /  0.77 ms |  ---- %] Pattern [/getpattern1(/)?] is NOT matched
X-Jersey-Tracing-011: MATCH       [ ---- /  0.77 ms |  ---- %] Pattern [/getpattern2(/)?] is NOT matched
X-Jersey-Tracing-012: MATCH       [ ---- /  0.78 ms |  ---- %] Pattern [/getpattern3(/)?] is NOT matched
X-Jersey-Tracing-013: MATCH       [ 0.09 /  0.79 ms |  7.47 %] RequestMatching summary
X-Jersey-Tracing-014: RESP-FILTER [ 0.23 /  1.18 ms | 18.96 %] Filter by [org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter @76ccd017 #-2147483648]
X-Jersey-Tracing-015: RESP-FILTER [ 0.26 /  1.19 ms | 21.52 %] Response summary: 1 filters
X-Jersey-Tracing-016: FINISHED    [ ---- /  1.21 ms |  ---- %] Response status: 404/CLIENT_ERROR|Not Found
Date: Sun, 17 Apr 2016 18:19:08 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

Is there something simple that I am missing, or do I need to somehow enable fancier pattern matching somewhere?

Comment: Just discovered that if I generalise the more specific method to @Path("/prefix/{param1:.*}/{param2:.*}") then it still triggers. Of course this means I don't get the parameters. Seems to be something about having the extra arguments or the annotations that stops it.

Comment: Stop press: it's the arguments... The method still doesn't trigger if I turn off the @PathParam annotations.

Comment: OK - mystery solved. For some reason the @Path annotations for parameterised methods need to be directly on the actual method rather than the interface. Not sure why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my original answer:

> Jax-RS 2.0 annotations for parameterised Jersey methods need to be placed next to the implementation - if they are just placed in a parent interface they are not picked up (at least in Jersey 22.2.2).

Refinement: the above is only true if there is already a Jax-RS 2.0 annotation on the overriding/implementing method - in this case, `@PathParam`. In this case, the spec mandates that any parent Jax-RS 2.0 annotations are disregarded. Thanks to peeskillet for pointing this out.

> This may be because `@Path` is not an `@Inherited` annotation (possibly because inherited annotations can be problematic because of multiple inheritance).

Refinement: The Jax-RS 2.0 spec seems to mandate that any implementation/overridden methods will inherit Jax-RS annotations from the parent, and doesn't specify that this will necessarily be based on standard annotation inheritance, so perhaps something else is at work in Jersey.

Comment: [That's not true](https://gist.github.com/psamsotha/dfc9657290bb51b44ef640139974082b). See my comment in 
Cássio's answer. Could that possibly be the case? Note that even adding `@PathParam` in the method parameter of the overridden method applies as adding an annotation, so it negates all interface annotations.

Comment: Looking at the spec, it shouldn't be true, but it did appear to be so when I tested with JDK8 and Jersey 22.2.2.

Comment: I don't think you are understanding my comment. Look at my code I linked to. Maybe you will understand it better. Once you add _any_ JAX-RS annotations to the overridden method, it overrides _all_ annotations from the interface. This includes even adding a `@PathParam` annotation. The overridden method should _not_ have the `@PathParam` annotation. This will override _all_ annotations from the interface. That is the point I am making. It has nothing to do with the `@Path` annotation with parameters.

Comment: A-ha! I missed that the implemented class had the `@PathParam` annotation as well. Jersey is therefore behaving as the JAX-RS 2.0 spec describes, and obliterating the parent `@Path` annotation. Many thanks for going to the trouble of doing your own test. I will edit my own answer, but if you wish to add your own feel free. :)

Answer (score 2):

The section regarding *annotation inheritance* of the [JAX-RS 2.0](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/jaxrs-2_0-fr-eval-spec/jsr339-jaxrs-2.0-final-spec.pdf) specification is pretty clear. See the quote below:

> ### 3.6 Annotation Inheritance
>
> JAX-RS annotations may be used on the methods and method parameters of a super-class or an implemented interface. Such annotations are inherited by a corresponding sub-class or implementation class method provided that the method and its parameters do not have any JAX-RS annotations of their own. Annotations on a super-class take precedence over those on an implemented interface. The precedence over conflicting annotations defined in multiple implemented interfaces is implementation specific. Note that inheritance of class or interface annotations is not supported.
>
> If a subclass or implementation method has any JAX-RS annotations then *all* of the annotations on the superclass or interface method are ignored. E.g.:
>
> ```java
> public interface ReadOnlyAtomFeed {
>     @GET 
>     @Produces("application/atom+xml")
>     Feed getFeed();
> }
>
> @Path("feed")
> public class ActivityLog implements ReadOnlyAtomFeed {
>     public Feed getFeed() {...}
> }
> ```
>
> In the above, `ActivityLog.getFeed` inherits the `@GET` and `@Produces` annotations from the interface. Conversely:
>
> ```java
> @Path("feed")
> public class ActivityLog implements ReadOnlyAtomFeed {
>     @Produces("application/atom+xml")
>     public Feed getFeed() {...}
> }
> ```
>
> In the above, the `@GET` annotation on `ReadOnlyAtomFeed.getFeed` is not inherited by `ActivityLog.getFeed` and it would require its own request method designator since it redefines the `@Produces` annotation.
>
> For consistency with other Java EE specifications, it is recommended to always repeat annotations instead of relying on annotation inheritance.

---

For some reason, the only annotations of the [`javax.ws.rs`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/package-summary.html) package annotated with [`@Inherited`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Inherited.html) are [`@Consumes`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/Consumes.html) and [`@Produces`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/Produces.html).

Comment: [The inheritance only applies to class level annotations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Inherited.html), not method annotations. So the first half of the spec doesn't apply to this case. What _should_ be taken from it is the last couple paragraphs, mentioning that adding even a single annotation on the overridden method negates _all_ annotation from the interface, and needs to be reapplied to the override. This _could_ be the OPs problem, but they have not provided enough code to make that determination; specifically, the overridden method code.

Comment: Peeskillet - I think this is generally true, but it seems the Jax-RS spec mandates a different behaviour, where JAX-RS annotations are inherited from parent classes/interfaces, except when one or more JAX-RS annotations are already present. Which doesn't explain why the inheritance doesn't occur here. The fact that, as Cassio states,  the `@Path` annotation isn't `@Inherited` in Jersey may be related... Or perhaps Jersey builds its own model of inheritance internally.