# Limiting the values of Query Params JAX-RS with CXF as implementation

Tags: java, spring, rest, jax-rs, cxf

I have a use case where I need to limit the values that can be passed as the query param.

```
@Path("/foo")
public interface Foo {

    @GET
    @Path("/details/id/{id}")
    void getFooDetails(@PathParam("id") String id, @QueryParam("sort") String sortDirection);
}

public class FooImpl {
    public void getFooDetails(String id, String sortDir) {
        //Implementation
    }
}
```

In the above example, I want to restrict the value of query param `sort` that can be passed via the API to `ASC, DESC`.

Is there any existing CXF annotation which I can use to restrict the values on a parameter? I haven't found any and so I tried the following solution.

**My Approach:**

```
@Target({ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Inherited
public @interface ValueSet {

    String[] allowedValues();
}
```

The modified interface looks like this.

```
@Path("/foo")
public interface Foo {

    @GET
    @PathParam("/details/id/{id}")
    void getFooDetails(@PathParam("id") String id, @QueryParam("sort") @ValueSet(allowedValues = {"ASC", "DESC"}) String sortDirection);
}
```

I wrote a CXF Interceptor which intercepts the API invocation. I used reflection to get a handle on `FooImpl.getFooDetails` params. But the problem I faced is that the interceptor looks at FooImpl.getFooDetails method and doesn't find the annotations @QueryParam on the method params since @QueryParam is on the base method and the annotation is not inherited.

Interceptor implementation:

```
@Provider
public class ParamValidationInterceptor extends AbstractPhaseInterceptor<Message> {

    public ParamValidationInterceptor() {
        super(Phase.PRE_INVOKE);
        super.addBefore(someInterceptor);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message message) throws Fault {

        UriInfo uriInfo = new UriInfoImpl(message);
        MultivaluedMap<String, String> queryParams = uriInfo.getQueryParameters();
        Method methodToInvoke = (Method) message.get("org.apache.cxf.resource.method");
        Parameter[] parameters = methodToInvoke.getParameters();
        for (Parameter parameter : parameters) {

            if (parameter.isAnnotationPresent(ValueSet.class)) {
                ValueSet valueSet = parameter.getAnnotation(ValueSet.class);
                QueryParam queryParam = parameter.getAnnotation(QueryParam.class);
                Object invokedVal = queryParams.get(queryParam.value());

                String[] allowedValues = valueSet.allowedValues();

                if (!Arrays.asList(allowedValues).contains(invokedVal)) {
                    throw new CustomException();
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Can anyone suggest a way forward? It would be great if anyone can suggest an alternative approach.

P.S: I am using CXF as an implementation for JAX-RS and spring is used as a container.

**Update:**

Like @Cássio Mazzochi Molin and @Andy McCright suggested, I will go with @Pattern annotation. But I am curious to know why the JAX-RS annotations are not inherited from the interface although the spec says they will be inherited.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Annotation inheritance

According to the section **§3.6 Annotation Inheritance** of the [JAX-RS specification](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/jaxrs-2_0-fr-eval-spec/jsr339-jaxrs-2.0-final-spec.pdf), it is recommended to always repeat annotations instead of relying on annotation inheritance.

Refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36693384/1426227) for the complete quote.

### `@QueryParam` can be applied to different targets

Bear in mind that the [`@QueryParam`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/QueryParam.html) annotation can be applied to:

- Resource method parameters
- Resource class fields
- Resource class bean properties

Hence a manual validation can be tricky.

### Use Bean Validation

For validation purposes, you should consider [Bean Validation](http://beanvalidation.org/). Consider a [`@Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/constraints/Pattern.html) annotation with the allowed values:

```java
@Pattern(regexp = "ASC|DESC")
```

And just annotate your resource method parameter:

```java
@GET
@Path("foo")
public Response getFoos(@QueryParam("sort") 
                        @Pattern(regexp = "ASC|DESC") String sortDirection) {
    ...
}
```

If you prefer case insensitive values, use:

```java
@Pattern(regexp = "ASC|DESC", flags = Pattern.Flag.CASE_INSENSITIVE)
```

If the given value is invalid, a [`ConstraintViolationException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/ConstraintViolationException.html) will be thrown. To handle such exception and return a customized response, you can use an [`ExceptionMapper`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/ExceptionMapper.html):

```java
@Provider 
public class ConstraintViolationExceptionMapper 
        implements ExceptionMapper<ConstraintViolationException> {

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(ConstraintViolationException exception) {
        ...
    } 
}
```

Comment: The spec in the other answer talks about annotation inheritance. It says that annotations are inherited given that there are no annotations on the extended class. Although the recommended approach is to repeat the annotations, I choose not to do that in order to maintain the API spec on the interfaces in a cleaner way. But the spec says that the annotations are inherited in case there are no annotations on the extended class. But I am not able to access the annotations by having a handle to method object of the concrete class. I would like to be able to access the annotations from base class.

Comment: Mazzochi Molin, Pattern annotation doesn't seem to work for me. I have javax validation jar and hibernate validator in maven dependencies. Is there anything else I need to do for this to work? I am using spring in tomcat container with cxf as jax rs implementation. I presume there is a spring proxy created which validates the method args whenever this method is called. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @yaswanth You probably are missing any configuration. Check the documentation: http://cxf.apache.org/docs/validationfeature.html

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps it is just a typo, but CXF may not be recognizing the getFooDetails method (on the interface) because it is annotated with @PathParam instead of @Path.

Instead of using your ValueSet approach, I used BeanValidation, but the following code works for me.

Foo.java

```
@Path("/foo")
public interface Foo {

    @GET
    @Path("/details/id/{id}")
    Response getFooDetails(
            @PathParam("id") @Pattern(regexp="[0-9]*") String id,
            @QueryParam("sort") @Pattern(regexp = "ASC|DESC") String sortDirection);
}
```

FooImpl.java

```
public class FooImpl implements Foo {

    @Override
    public Response getFooDetails(String id, String sortDirection) {
        Integer idInt = Integer.parseInt(id);
        if ("ASC".equals(sortDirection) || sortDirection == null) {
            ...
        } else if ("DESC".equals(sortDirection)) {
            ...
        }
        return ...;
    }
```

I've got this working on WebSphere Liberty 17.0.0.2 which is based on CXF 3.1.11.

Hope this helps,
Andy

Comment: I would still suggest using BeanValidation.  It is certainly simpler than using an interceptor to check for annotations on the resource impl class.  And it looks like somebody else thinks it is a good idea too. ;)

Comment: I agree with you. I will go with the @Pattern annotation. But I am curious to know why I am not able to access JAXRS annotations of the interface from the concrete class.

Comment: Can you post your interceptor code?  I'm just wondering if there is something wrong with the reflection methods used - getDeclaredAnnotations vs getParameterAnnotations, etc.

Comment: I have added the interceptor implementation. JAX-RS annotations are not annotated with Inherited annotation. I think that's the reason the concrete class method object is not finding them. But this contradicts with the JAX-RS spec about annotation inheritance.

Comment: The javadoc for the @Inherited annotation says that it only works for classes: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Inherited.html
So even if the JAX-RS annotations were Inherited, I don't think you'd be able to see them from checking the parameters.  You might be able to see the annotations by checking the OperationResourceInfo (you should be able to get it from the exchange - message.getExchange.get(OperationResourceInfo.class)).

Comment: Right. I will be able to get the query params, path params etc from OperationResourceInfo.class but that won't have information about which method argument it belongs to.

Comment: I will have to accept the other answer as that is answered first.